# Invalid Property Value CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a dynamic linearly decreasing width to a side nav with css below a certain breakpoint until it hits a minimum value. Currently it's just stepping between two values for some reason and saying the following is an invalid property value. I think it's due to the px and vw units being different but I don't know how else to add it

```css
width: calc(160px - 65px * ( ( 1345px - 100vw ) / 65 ) );
```

Operator spacing looks fine to me and if I remove the difference it has no issue so this is what makes me think it's a unit difference. I tried wrapping the difference with another calc or placing it under root but this didn't work.
Here's the relevant css:

```css
@media (min-width: 1345px) {
    .sidenav {
        width: 160px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .homeblock {
        width: 160px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .sidenav {
        width: calc(160px - 65px * ( ( 1345px - 100vw ) / 65 ) );
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
    }
}
```

Tried varying units, changing the expression, wrapping it and more. Also tried looking to get the window width in pixels through another method but see no other examples.

Comment: Is the calculation producing a negative width?

Comment: I do not believe so but don't know how to check. It looks to be a simple unit mismatch issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should be easier and work faster

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .homeblock {
        width: 160px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .sidenav {
        width: calc( min(160px, 95px + (65px * (1345px - 100vw) / 65px) ));
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
    }
}
```

Comment: The min() function ensures the width doesn't drop below 95px.
The calculation inside the min() function dynamically changes the width based on the viewport width.

Comment: That gave the same error and results but I just fiddled with it some more and the following gives the desired effect for some reason now it's just adjusting. The min should help though
```css
width: calc(160px - 10 * ( calc( 1345px - 100vw ) / 65 ) )
```

Comment: I just need the right conversion here to the pixels I desire

Comment: give it a try to this
`width: calc(160px - 65px * ((100 - (100vw / 1345)) / 65));`

Comment: This also did not work out and think the units here probably don't work at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work which is what I was hoping for along with adding a min as per @Felpower 's answer

```css
width: calc(min(160px, 160px - 10 * ( calc( 1345px - 100vw ) / 65 ) ));
```

It might not be precise as I don't understand the conversions here on the 10 scale factor but it's a simple adjustment.

Comment: A bit clunky but this gave me exactly what I wanted 
```css
width: calc(min(160px, max(95px, 160px - 10 * ( calc( 1345px - 100vw ) / 65 ) )));
```
The scale factor just adjusts the speed at this point.